# Batch script that delete old Backups and keep just one

Tags: oracle, shell, batch-file, scripting, backup

I start a script `--command=STATISTICS --statdata=SAVEPOINTS > C:\Safepoints.txt`
 that generates an output like this.

```
Page count for each save point version:
  0: version=0, status=3, ts=2014-03-18 16:24:51.764, page count=68861
  1: version=1, status=3, ts=2014-03-18 17:49:25.622, page count=68861
  2: version=2, status=3, ts=2014-03-19 05:00:10.467, page count=68925
  3: version=3, status=2, ts=2014-03-20 14:05:53.267, page count=2744
  4: version=4, status=3, ts=2014-03-20 15:08:40.607, page count=68859
  5: version=5, status=3, ts=2014-03-21 05:00:10.527, page count=68926
```

My Idea is, to read the C:\Safepoint.txt and check if existing more then one file with status=3 (full backup) than keep the latest file, else start a new command like this

```
--command=DELETE_SAVEPOINTS 0-4
```

I modified the script as follows but it stucks before the

> for loop after > %mytempfile%

```
@echo on

set last=-1

set mytempfile=%TEMP%\%random%.out
%ORACLE%\bin\OracleDatabase.bat --dbtype=ORACLE --database=orca --hostname=test.ora.db --port=5645 --user=sa --password=***** --command=STATISTICS --statdata=SAVEPOINTS > %mytempfile%

for /f "tokens=1 delims=: " %%a in ('type %mytempfile% ^| find "status=3" ') do  set /a last=%%a
for /f "tokens=1 delims=: " %%a in ('type %mytempfile% ^| find "status=3" ') do (
if %last% neq %%a (
 %Oracle%\bin\OracleDatabase.bat --dbtype=ORACLE --database=orca --hostname=test.ora.db --port=5645 --user=sa --password=***** --command=DELETE_SAVEPOINTS %%a
)
) 

del /q %mytempfile%
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to undertand what/when to ask for savepoint deletion, but..

```
@echo off
set "last=-1"
for /f "tokens=1 delims=: " %%a in ('findstr /l /c:"status=3" safepoint.txt') do set /a "last=%%a-1"
if %last% geq 0 (
    RunWhatEver --command=DELETE_SAVEPOINTS 0-%last%
)
```

It searchs for the last line with `status=3` and retrieves the initial number. If it is greater or equal to 0, a line is found and the script is called to remove anything from 0 to the savepoint that precedes the last full backup

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that the script does not run the `RunWhatEver --command=DELETE_SAVEPOINTS 0 - %last%` command

Comment: @Ahmetfam, obviously the `runwhatever` should be replaced with your script. If you have already done it, what is the result? If you place an `echo %last%` before the `if ...` line, what does it echo to console?

Comment: please see my code again, maybe you can see why the script dies before the for loop.

Comment: @Ahmetfam, your `OracleDatabase` is a batch file. If, from a batch file, you directly call another batch file, the execution is transfered to the called batch, and does not return to the caller. You need to use `call OracleDatabase.bat ....` for the execution to continue on the caller.

Comment: @Ahmetfam, and, Why the second `for` loop?

Comment: it counts incremental, that's why i set the second loop 'if %last% neq %%a'

Comment: @Ahmetfam, i don't know anything about how `oracleDatabase.bat` works, but if instead of running only one command to delete all the "savepoints" (i don't know if this can be done) you run one command for each of them, maybe (and this is just an hypothesis) the numbering of the savepoints change with each deletion and the code, as is, will fail. If it happens, you will have to obtain the position for the full savepoint after each deletetion.

Comment: I mean maybe i have a syntax error in the script, because it fit my needs if it works